# Android Test Case Activity Testing

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, android-testing

I have an activity with ListView and CustomCursorAdapter now I wish to automate testing. Every thing is fine but when there is no record in the adapter there is a Alert Dialog is visible on screen now the **problem** is that I can not accessing the alert dialog on activity testing (android test case ) and not able to handle alert dialog event on testing framework, sir please help me on this regards. thanks in advance.

**Dialog create code.**

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

    String msg = null;
    switch(id){
    case CALL_SETTING:
        builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("CIH - HELP");         
        msg = "Please Allow me to guide you Configure this fresh CIH-MA.";                  
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new settingOnClickListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new cancelOnClickListener());
        alDialog = builder.create();
        alDialog.show();
        break;
    case CALL_SITE:
        builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("CIH - HELP");
        msg = "Please press 'Site' button to Add new Site for Monitoring and Controling Device ";
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new siteOnClickListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new cancelOnClickListener());
        alDialog = builder.create();
        alDialog.show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);

}
private final class settingOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ZigbeeActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(ZigbeeActivity.this,AboutScreen.class));           
    }       
}
private final class cancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }       
}
private final class siteOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent LocationIntent = new Intent(ZigbeeActivity.this,SelectLocation.class);
        LocationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ZigbeeActivity.this.startActivity(LocationIntent);
    }       
}
```

Comment: change AlertDialog.Builder(this); to AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);

Comment: Actually sir this AlertDialog.Builder code is written on the Testing Activity and through JUnit how I handle alertDialog events

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of refactoring you could use [BoundBox](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/boundbox) to access the private state of your activity.

For instance, put all code inside your listeners inside private methods of your activity, and test them using a mock context to see if intents are received correctly.